# Vim puts random characters in command bar on startup

Tags: vim, configuration

I seem to be having a problem with vim, where when I open up vim (not gvim, gvim doesn't do this), it puts a bunch of random characters into the command bar. For example, when I type `vim test.txt` it will open up test.txt fine, but there will be some form of characters like `.2802;0c` typed as a command.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Thanks for any help!

---

Here is my .vimrc:

```
" =========== Info ==============
" VimRC File
" Author: Mark Asp
" Purpose: Store overall Vim settings
"   that are specific to the editing
"   environment.
" ===============================

" ==== Use ViM rather than Vi ====
set nocompatible
" ================================

" ========== Pathogen ============
execute pathogen#infect()
filetype indent plugin on
" ================================

" ======= General Settings =======  

let mapleader=","                " Set the map leader to , for ease of use

set nomodeline                   " Don't allow modelines as they are vim only 



" --- Color Settings --
syntax on                        " Enable syntax coloring
set t_Co=256
colorscheme harlequin
" ---------------------

set relativenumber               " Show the relative line number

set backspace=indent,eol,start   " Allow backspace to transcend lines
" ================================

" ========== Mappings ============

" Load mappings from ~/.vim/mappings.vim
if filereadable(expand("~/.vim/mappings.vim"))
  source ~/.vim/mappings.vim
endif

set notimeout ttimeout           " Time out for key codes only
set ttimeoutlen=1000              " Wait 200 millis

" ================================

" ========== Formatting ==========

" ---- Indentation ----
set shiftwidth=4                 " Set the tab width to 4 spaces
set tabstop=4                    " Set the tab width to 4 spaces
set expandtab                    " Convert tabs to spaces
" ---------------------

" ----- Wrapping ------
set wrap                         " Only wrap visually
set linebreak                    " Don't cut a word in half while wrapping
" ---------------------

" ================================ }}}

" ======= Window Settings =======

set hidden                       " Allow buffers to be hidden in the background
set confirm                      " Always ask for confirmation
set t_vb=                        " Do no visual things

" ---- Bottom Bar -----
set showcmd                      " Show the command being typed
set cmdheight=1                  " Make the command line 1 character tall 
set wildmenu                     " Complete for commands 
set laststatus=2                 " Make it so that status only shows with 2 or
                                 "    more windows
" ---------------------

" ================================

" ======= Search Settings ========

set hlsearch                     " Highlight search results
set smartcase                    " If all is lower, ingore case, if there is a
                                 "    capital letter, include it.

" ================================

" ============ Movement ==========

set nostartofline                " Keep cursor position when switching lines

" ================================

" ========= Persistance ==========

" Keep undo history across sessions
" by storing all changes all time
silent !mkdir ~/.vim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
set undodir=~/.vim/backups
set undofile

" Turn off all swap files
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set nowb

" ================================

" ====== Custom File Types =======

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.frag,*.vert,*.fp,*.vp,*.glsl setf glsl

" ================================

" ======== GVim Settings =========
set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono\ 10
set guioptions-=m " remove menu bar
set guioptions-=T " remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r " remove right-hand scrollbar
set guioptions-=l " remove left-hand scrollbar

" ================================

" ======== CTag Settings =========
set tags+=~/.vim/tags
" ================================
```

Comment: This looks like some unrecognized ANSI escape codes. What's your terminal and value of `$TERM`?!

Comment: Currently I'm using xterm for $TERM.

Comment: What other plugins are installed?  Try disabling them to see if you can induce a change in behavior.

Comment: Do you use ssh or screen or tmux?

Answer (score 0):

I use your vimrc file and comment out the following line. After that, I do not come across the random characters on the command bar and it works fine. I think maybe some plugins of your vim cause it. (I test it on the  linux server of my lab.)

```
14 "execute pathogen#infect()
28 "colorscheme harlequin
31 "set relativenumber  
98 "set undodir=~/.vim/backups
99 "set undofile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but mine was caused by this junk in my .vimrc and fixed when I commented / removed these lines.

```
augroup myCmds
au!
autocmd VimEnter * silent !echo -ne "\e[2 q"
autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\e[1 q"
augroup END
```